# What might be the reasons for Performance tool data is high. [ showing in Xcode VM tracker]

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I recently profiled my app using Xcode VM tracker instrument.I found that app has lot of dirty memory especially performance tool data. So i want to know what are the reasons of the huge dirty memory and performance tool data.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: Maybe proper coding conventions not followed. You can fix these memory issues by reviewing it.

Comment: Could you guide me any doc referring those stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Your app takes 51MB to store, when it is suspended. The performance tool itself adds an overhead of 30MB. Which leaves 20MB for your app.

From the listed items, it looks like your app is graphics heavy. In fact, it looks very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15490280/5276890). Which makes me wonder if these objects are still processing or waiting to be released, when the app is suspended.

Alternatively, I wonder if you could free a lot of those animations and images when entering background, and reconstruct them when entering foreground.

Finally, note that [Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW28) removing strong references to images, data from disk and media to reduce dirty memory.

Answer (score 2):

Since I just had the same problem, here is what I found:
The "Performance tool data" entries were from libBacktraceRecording.dylib.

You can disable backtrace recording in the scheme editor.

See the related question [Memory leak with “libBacktraceRecording.dylib” in React Native ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336920/memory-leak-with-libbacktracerecording-dylib-in-react-native-ios-application/34479178#34479178).