# Memory leak with "libBacktraceRecording.dylib" in React Native ios application

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, react-native

When I'm trying to run a basic react native application I see a lot of `libBacktraceRecording.dylib` memory request for 544 KB. The same thing with another applications.

[image]

Can you help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You are running (probably a debug build) with backtrace recording enabled.
Disable it in the scheme editor and those allocations will go away.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU -- I was going INSANE over this!  We have a 3D drawing engine that runs ALL kinds of content, so it looked like GL was just leaking internally because no allocations were showing up.

Comment: Son of a donkey!  I went crazy trying to figure out where my game was leaking!

Comment: You're a super hero!