# Memory eaten by [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c

When setting the background color of `buttons` in the mainQueue, I can see the iOS device's memory usage go up by a few hundred kilobyte per click. This is the code I am using:

```
for(int i=0; i<99;i++){

    int x=arc4random_uniform(8);
    int y=arc4random_uniform(8);

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

    if(i%2==0)
        [buttons[x][y] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    else
        [buttons[x][y] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    }];
```

The queue gets executed just fine but doesn't seem to release the `buttons` afterwards. I tried using ARC which doesn't do anything, probably it doesn't recognize it as a leak. If I remove the code which makes the colors alternate (just setting the same color every time), there is no increase in memory usage.

I I put no single statement in the queue, it also does not occupy memory so I am sure it's the `buttons` that zombie around somewhere. **However, I don't know how to locate/clear them from there.**

A solution that works with ARC would be much appreciated.

EDIT: if I set the backgroundColor without employing the mainQueue there is no increase in memory usage.

EDIT 2: this is how instruments look. I can't see anything specific that takes all the memory, some values seem to increase linear to how often I click. Please tell me if there is something else I could click to get more details
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's no memory leak or retain-cycle evident in what you posted.  Can you use Instruments to see which objects are staying alive?

Comment: Hey mate I attached some screenshots

Comment: This code does not have any leaked, abandoned, or cached memory problems. I ran it through leaks/allocations tool with zero memory growth. The problem is undoubtedly a result of some scheme setting (e.g. see "enable queue backtracing" option: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34336920/1271826) and/or instruments recording settings (e.g. turning on zombies will cause this sort of growth).

Comment: Cheers Rob you were absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Rob guessed, "backtrace recording" was enabled.

Taken from the answer at [Memory leak with "libBacktraceRecording.dylib" in React Native ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336920/memory-leak-with-libbacktracerecording-dylib-in-react-native-ios-application) you have to remove the tick in the "edit scheme" popup

[image]